# How to check the ARIMA model by simulating innovations?

Tags: time-series, simulation, arima, residuals

I am working on a monthly river flow time series and somebody has asked me to check my model by simulating innovations (or something like that). Can somebody help me about how can we simulate and how can check my model with that? I appreciate if you suggest a article or document in this regard.

Also, if my question is wrong and this can not be done let me know so I will delete it.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify some basics - firstly, do you have a univariate data set, with regular observations on a single variable that is "river flow"?  If not, are there any other variables in the model?  Secondly do you know if they mean innovation in this sense: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innovation_(signal_processing) (seems likely) - or in some other perhaps less technical sense eg a change in river management.

Comment: @Peter Eilis : my observations are monthly discharge time series so  it is univariate and yes by innovations I mean residuals of my ARMA model (in my case I have fitted an AR(1) )